# Google Drive API (PHP): some files missing parent reference

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm still learning the ins and outs of the Google Drive API. I'm trying to create a file browser for it that displays items in a hierarchical structure rather than displaying all files listed regardless of its parent.

The problem I came across was that there were some files with empty parents arrays. The idea is initially that it should show all files that exist in root, and only root, and then when a folder is clicked show its children.

However, the missing parent data has confused me.

Is this because those files have been shared with me and therefore do not have a parent reference in relation to me? If so, how can I identify such files? Using empty() on the returned parent data does not seem to recognise it as an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick test and I get the same results.
It makes sense that you should not be given any visibility of the parents of a shared file.

To know if a file is shared, look at the userPermission array.

**Owned...**

```
 "userPermission": {
    "kind": "drive#permission",
    "id": "me",
    "role": "owner",
    "type": "user"
   },
```

**Shared...**

```
"userPermission": {
    "kind": "drive#permission",
    "id": "me",
    "role": "writer",
    "type": "user"
   },
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, this is basically what i assumed, however i was going to use the "sharedWithMeDate" value to check if it was shared however your's appears to be a more sensible choice. Thanks again for the reply

Comment: I think it depends what you're looking to achieve. It's possible for ownership to be transferred. Checking permissions will list files for which you are now the owner, regardless of how that came about. Checking for sharedWithMeDate will look for files that were shared with you, regardless of whether or not you are now the owner.

You also have the option of querying within the owners collection q="not 'foo@bar.com' in owners"

Comment: I see, i never considered ownership transferal, just noticed the "sharedWithMeDate" field only existed in files that had been shared, thank you for pointing out this oversight

Comment: after playing around with sharing on Google drive it has became clear that empty parents are not related to ownership of the file or whether or not the file is shared, i am now back to square one with this.